# Windows Phone TextBox alignment in grid

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have below code in the XAML.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
       <RowDefinition/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="2" Foreground="Black" Text="Username"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="1" Foreground="Black" Background="AliceBlue"/>
</Grid>
```

When I run the above code the alignment of textblock and textbox are not same left aligned. How can I make text block and textbox with same left alignment without using margin?

Screen shot

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=29BEFDB80421523A!141&authkey=!ADxPSwAg7LhuhkU&v=3&ithint=photo%2c.png

Comment: `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` or `TextAlignment="Left"` on your `TextBox` or show an image of what you're getting to help visualize your issue.

Answer (score 0):

[TextBox has its own default stye](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645061(v=vs.95).aspx) and some its values you cannot normally override without changing its style. Probably you will have to change default Padding and Margin (what I see that at that link Padding = 2).

To ensure I would advise to open you Page.xaml in Blend, click on TextBox, Edit Template -> Edit a copy ([here you have](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23049159/2681948) good screenshots). The same with TextBlock (follow the question from previous link). When you set the same padding and margin, then your elements should be aligned the same.